# Writing a Function with a list from a stored Calculation

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I'm trying to write a function for CLV that stores the values for each year, indexed 0 to t, in a list and sums the list. What I have:

```
CLV_simple <- function (r, t, M, Alpha){
  CLV = list()
  for (i in 0:t){
    CLV[i] <-  M*(Alpha/(1+r))^i
    return(sum(CLV))
  }
}
CLV_simple(.10, 4, M, Alpha)
```

where CLV[0] = M*(Alpha/(1+r))^0,
CLV[1] = M*(Alpha/(1+r))^1, so on to CLV[4].

Alpha and M are defined as variables earlier. Assume Alpha is .81 and M is 40.23

the return should be the sum of each year or:

```
(M*(Alpha/(1+.10))^0) + (M*(Alpha/(1+.10))^1) + (M*(Alpha/(1+.10))^2) + (M*(Alpha/(1+.10))^3) + (M*(Alpha/(1+.10))^4)

[1] 121.4646
```

When I run my function all I get is this:

```
CLV_simple(.10, 4, M, Alpha)
list()
```

so something isn't being saved to the list right and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code,

1. `return` makes your code jump out of `for` loop after the first iteration. You should move `return` to the end of your function body where `for` loops are done.
2. Also, `i` is an index to access `CLV`, which should starts from `1` instead of `0` from `0:t`.
3. One more thing, `CLV` should be initialized as `c()`, since elements in `list()` cannot summed up directly.

---

You can try `for` loop like below

```
CLV_simple <- function (r, t, M, Alpha){
  CLV <- c()
  for (i in 0:t){
    CLV[i+1] <-  M*(Alpha/(1+r))^i  
  }
  return(sum(CLV))
}
```

or a simpler one

```
CLV_simple2 <- function(r,t,M,Alpha) sum(M*(Alpha/(1+r))^(0:t))
```